# Keep boost asio io_service

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I usually keep one io_service object for the whole application and use a number of threads to call run on them. Creating sockets or timers use the io_service by reference. What happens when all threads finish at application exit and there is, lets say a shutdown or cancel operation called on a tcp socket. The io_service is no longer available. Is there a copy of the io_service when passing that to any asio related classed or is that undefined behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never a copy of `io_service` (or the more recent `io_context` that replaces the deprecated `io_service`). That's because it's not copyable.

If you don't maintain the lifetime while async operations have not completed, the behaviour is indeed undefined. However, it's not too hard to make sure no async operations/completions happen by stopping the service forcibly gracefully awaiting for it to complete any pending operations.

I suggest the latter approach for production quality code.